# Function that should accept vector<int> accepts int. Is that an error?

Tags: c++11

I wrote a small function accepting an `vector` of int values.

```
void transform(vector<int> i) {
    // actual code
}

int i = 5;
transform(5);
```

Now if I pass a single int value to the function it accepts it without
any compiler warnings. Am I missing something fundamental here or does C++ some kind of magic auto packaging for me?

I used clang to compile the code and enabled all warnings with `-Wall`.

Comment: I think your `int i` is casted to a `vector<int>` automatically

Comment: or rather, are you sure, you have no other overloads of transform?

Comment: That shouldn't really work, as no non-explicit [`std::vector` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) takes a single `int` argument or a single argument of the contained type.

Comment: No, the function appears nowhere else and has only this single definition, no method overloading.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6099b781deffe7b1). Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am deeply sorry. I checked the code base again and saw that the Concstructor was overloaded. Sorry for the inconvenience.